# React.cloneElement() is called every render

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React code.

```
function CustomButton(props){
  return (
    <>
      {!props.frequentlyChanged && <span>Nope</span>
      {props.frequentlyChanged && React.cloneElement(props.button, {/* do something */})}
    </>
  )
}
```

I have a property `frequentlyChanged`. It is literally changed frequently.
And I am using `React.cloneElement()` with it.

I am worried about that usage because I think it is inefficient to render every time `frequentlyChanged` changed.

If I can, I want to make it more efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: React components rerender every time when state or props update, so... do you have a more specific concern?

Comment: I mean, rerender with `React.cloneElement()` is ok or not.

Comment: why not just use {props.frequentlyChanged && props.button}  ..
why cloning?

Comment: @Vikrant I added `/* */` in the code. sometimes, I inject `ref` or `onClick`